# How to set parameters names for python nodes in roslaunch

Tags: python, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to automate a `rosrun` into a `roslaunch`. My command is shown below:

```
rosrun robotiq_2f_gripper_control Robotiq2FGripperRtuNode.py /dev/ttyUSB0
```

**Problem:**

I can not find a way to pass my argument as a parameter. The [source code](https://github.com/TAMS-Group/robotiq/blob/6d0d7474ab2b3ce9661c64f3b6f64551e7d24e98/robotiq_2f_gripper_control/nodes/Robotiq2FGripperRtuNode.py#L95) uses `sys.argv[1]` as the command line parameter. Is there a way to make this work in a launch file?

This is what I tried:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="robotiq_2f_gripper_control" type="Robotiq2FGripperRtuNode.py" name="Robotiq2FGripperRtuNode" output="screen">
    <param name="device" value="/dev/ttyUSB1" />
</launch>
```

However, the execution is similar to mistyping the name of the device port in the `rosrun` command. I can edit the source code. Furthermore, I know that I could call the `rosrun` command in a `.sh` script, but I would appreciate using the proper tool for the job.

Offending package: [TAMS-Group/robotiq](https://github.com/TAMS-Group/robotiq/blob/noetic-devel/robotiq_2f_gripper_control/nodes/Robotiq2FGripperRtuNode.py)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405956/how-to-set-parameters-names-for-python-nodes-in-roslaunch/) by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2022-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please use the `args` attribute of the `<node>` tag. To assist you better, I made a sample code. Please see below:

1. I created `my_args.launch` file as shown below:

   ```
    ravi@dell:~/ros_ws/src/ros_tutorials/rospy_tutorials/001_talker_listener$ cat my_args.launch 
    <launch>
        <node pkg="rospy_tutorials" type="listener.py" name="listener" args="/dev/ttyUSB0" output="screen" />
    </launch>
   ```
2. I edited the `listener.py` so that it can capture `sys.argv[1]` as shown below:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   # license removed for brevity
   import sys
   import rospy
   from std_msgs.msg import String

   def callback(data):
       rospy.loginfo(rospy.get_caller_id() + 'I heard %s', data.data)

   def listener(param):
       rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
       rospy.loginfo('param:' + param)
       rospy.Subscriber('chatter', String, callback)
       rospy.spin()

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       listener(sys.argv[1])
   ```
3. Finally, I ran the launch file. I can see the value in the terminal. Please see below:

   ```
    $ roslaunch rospy_tutorials my_args.launch 
    ... logging to /home/ravi/.ros/log/828983fa-2e9e-11ed-bbf8-d707e2da4a66/roslaunch-dell-90235.log
    Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
    Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
    Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

    started roslaunch server http://dell:33681/

    SUMMARY
    ========

    PARAMETERS
     * /rosdistro: noetic
     * /rosversion: 1.15.14

    NODES
      /
        listener (rospy_tutorials/listener.py)

    ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

    process[listener-1]: started with pid [90264]
    [INFO] [1662549440.441759]: param:/dev/ttyUSB0
    [INFO] [1662549452.298103]: /listenerI heard hello world 1662549452.294159
    [INFO] [1662549452.398594]: /listenerI heard hello world 1662549452.3944724
    [INFO] [1662549452.498860]: /listenerI heard hello world 1662549452.4945526
    [INFO] [1662549452.596540]: /listenerI heard hello world 1662549452.5943813
   ```

Please note that the original package in this post is taken from [ros/ros_tutorials](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/tree/noetic-devel/rospy_tutorials) repository.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on 2022-09-13**:
Thank you for your answer. Will try it out and let you know if that solve my problem.

**Comment by [Vic](https://answers.ros.org/users/68202/vic/) on 2022-09-13**:
Setting args="/dev/ttyUSB0" solved the issue. Thanks.